# Sharepoint Breadcrumbs (navigation)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, breadcrumb

I attempted to add the breadcrumbs into my Sharepoint Wiki Site, I use code like this:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" id="ContentMap" CssClass="BreadCrumbWrap" PathSeparator="&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;">
        <CurrentNodeStyle CssClass="BreadCrumbWrap" />
        <PathSeparatorStyle CssClass="BreadCrumbWrap" />  
        </asp:SiteMapPath>
```

But i didn't get the expected result. Now the breadcrumb leads to the library (folder), where the page is located.

E.g. Home --> Library --> Page from library

But my goal is to provide a breadcrumb, which leads to previous site - mother site.

E.g. Home --> Mother site with a link to child site --> Child Site

Do you have any ideas?